# Android Camera2 Request List for Bursts

Tags: android

I'm trying to take bursts using camera2 and the captureBurst function. I just can't figure out how to create the list of request required for the first argument. The documentation and samples I've seen use a builder to create the requests, and I can't figure out to extend it to List or how to save the images once they have been taken

Here's the documentation: [android camera2 documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#captureBurst%28java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler%29)

Sorry this is prob such a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general steps to create a List of requests for a captureBurst are:

1. CaptureRequest.Builder crb = camera.createCaptureRequest(TEMPLATE);
2. List<CaptureRequest> burstList = new ArrayList<CaptureRequest>();
3. For 1 to n exposures:

   - Set the appropriate parameters and output surfaces in your capture request builder.
   - burstList.add(crb.build());
4. session.captureBurst(burstList, ...);

As for saving the images once they're ready, I would suggest basically just copying the code/technique from the [Camera2Basic example code](http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/index.html). This involves associating an ImageReader's surface with each CaptureRequest in the burst and setting the ImageReader's onImageAvailableListener to start a saving procedure, such as the example's ImageSaver. You can probably use the ImageSaver almost directly, but you'll need to write code to choose different file names for each image to be saved, otherwise they will overwrite each other like the example code does.

Comment: Link is broken. I thik code moved here.
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic